# Set Retries for API Gateway, AWS Services Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I Have deployed a REST API through API Gateway, which integrated with AWS S3 Directly to create/upload objects.

Here few API Calls Failing with `Execution failed due to a network error communicating with endpoint`.

Is there any way to configure Retries?

Comment: Facing same issue here